# Heartbeat and automatically restart application on Heroku

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, monitoring, heartbeat

I know it's not the nice way, but does anyone of you know a service where I can run a heartbeat to my heroku application and if it fails for a couple of minutes to respond to call `heroku restart` and send me an email?

Would be a really nice feature for me...

Thanks a lot!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting the app would definitely not be the best solution.
heroku isn't 100% of the time available
See [their status page](https://status.heroku.com/uptime).

There is [pingdom](https://www.pingdom.com/) though, which will ping your app and notify you if it is down.
But won't take any action for you.

Comment: Ok... Do you know any service which offers something similar for free?